# Issue with installing Scipy in virtualenv on RaspBerryPI

Tags: python, scipy, pip, virtualenv

when i run: `pip install -v scipy` in the virtualenv of RPI, RPI freezes halfway through installation and i had to power off and on RPI to turn it on again.
I tried upgrading pip but the problem persisted and I can't seem to find out the reason why. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please only use relevant tags to your problem, I removed opencv one.

Answer (score 1):

At first, check the power supply and a CPU heatsink. My RPi was stuck very often during different long-term tasks, after I installed heastsink problem was gone.

Comment: To expand on that, the reason you have to spin for a while is that you're compiling scipy.  That might well cause the Pi to overheat or draw more current than the power supply can source.  I had a Pi lock up if you tried to use gcc and the wifi at the same time.  I fixed it with a better power supply.